# Access violation when calling strtok(); C++

Tags: c++, strtok

I'm having trouble with this bit of code:

```
char KernelFS::doesExist(char* fname){
    char part;
    char name[8];
    char ext[3];

    char* token;

    token = strtok(fname, "\\");
    strncpy(&part, token, 1);

    token = strtok(fname, "\\");
    strncpy(name, token, 8);

    token = strtok(fname, "\\");
    strncpy(ext, token, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and breaks when I run it at the first call of strtok(...) - Access violation writing location ...
No idea why :(

I call this function with:

KernelFS::doesExist("X:\test.exe");

the point is to separate the fname char array into 3 arrays;
one for the name of the partition,
one for the file name,
one for the file extension;

thanks for the help ! :)

Comment: Why when you have `std::string` you people use raw character arrays.

Comment: You never use `part`, `name`, `ext` after filling them in. If you modify your code to use them, remember that these are not strings (you have created char buffers with no null terminator)

Comment: one more thing: `\t` has a special meaning, if you want a single \ separator then use `X:\\test.exe`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example:

```
KernelFS::doesExist("X:\test.exe");
```

`"X:\test.exe"` is in fact of a `const char*` type, you cannot modify it. That raw string literal is allocated within a protected memory area, hence the error you have encountered.

> char * [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) ( **char *** str, const char * delimiters );
>
> str -
>   Notice that this string is **modified** by being broken into smaller strings (tokens).
>   Alternativelly, a null pointer may be specified, in which case the function continues scanning where a previous successful call to the function ended.

If you really want to use the [`<cstring>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring) library (not advised though), you should rather allocate your string on a stack instead of acquiring it from the program symbols' area.

```
char path[] = { "X:\\test.exe" };
KernelFS::doesExist(path);
```

However, it is advised that you switch to the [`<string>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string) library.

Comment: Also you should check that `KernelFS::doesExist()` doesn't receive a `NULL` pointer and that `strtok()` doesn't return NULL.

Comment: +1, @Alek988Alek And after that, pay close attention to how your `strncpy` will not terminate your file extension with a nullchar if the extension is 3-chars wide. Your buffers seem to all be 1-char short.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following modification:

```
char KernelFS::doesExist(char* fname)
{
    // Our variables.
    char part[2];
    char name[9];
    char ext[4];        
    char* token;

    // Initialize variables.
    memset(part, '\0', 2);
    memset(name, '\0', 9);
    memset(ext, '\0', 4);

    // If we receive an invalid string:
    if (fname == NULL)
        return -1; // Return error.

    // Process.
    if ((token = strtok(fname, "\\")) != NULL)
        strncpy(part, token, 1);
    if ((token = strtok(fname, "\\")) != NULL)
        strncpy(name, token, 8);
    if ((token = strtok(fname, "\\")) != NULL)
        strncpy(ext, token, 3);

    // If we retrieved the 3 variables:
    if (strlen(part) > 0 && strlen(name) > 0 && strlen(ext) > 0)
    {
        // Do something with part, name and ext here.
    }

    // Return success.
    return 0;
}
```

As Piotr S. says, pay attention to **call this function with a valid `char *`** (not a `const char *` or anything else).